# What's wrong with this preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using `file_get_contents` to read a `.html` file that has a table.

```
<table id="someTable" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td style="padding-left:25px;">Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td style="padding-left:25px;">another text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I use preg_match_all to read the table, I get nothing when I count `$matches[1]`

```
preg_match_all('/<table id="someTable" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">(.*)<\/table>/', $html, $matches);
$co = count($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Looking to parse HTML with regular expressions is almost certainly not the way to go. What are you looking to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add modifier `s` to your preg_match.

```
preg_match_all('/<table id="someTable" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">(.*)<\/table>/s', $html, $matches);
```

See http://ideone.com/3w0K2